Using TcpNetClientConnectionFactory and CachingClientConnectionFactory without rest of spring integration
So i am trying to write an integration against a server that is communication via raw Tcp with a custom protcol that has no end delimiter on messages.
Im wondering if it is possible to use the above factories without using the rest of spring integration. I tried making some type of test
 public void process(Event event) {
    try {
        final TcpConnectionSupport connection = cachedClientCF.getConnection();
        final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        connection.registerListener(message -> {
            final byte[] payload = (byte[]) message.getPayload();
            LOG.info("Payload: {}", new String(payload));
            countDownLatch.countDown();
            return true;
        });
        connection.send(new GenericMessage<>("Hello world"));
        countDownLatch.await();

        } catch (SoftEndOfStreamException e) {
            LOG.info("Stream closed because of EOF: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

This is just a very simple basic example, but im getting delays up to 5-7 seconds on a request, and when sending mutiple requests, i only get one response. As it seems that the Listener is not triggered until FIN ACK is sent (during closing). Which is understandable since i have nothing that tells java that the message has ended.
Im wondering if there is any way to use this by opening a connection, keep it open and then just write, read, write, read, write read after eachother if i know the sizes of the messages.
There is very little documentation on using just the factories, and such, i have treied reading through the source code to understand how it all works, but i cant really figure it out. It seems like the polling on the response is very slow, and it only checks if there is a response every 5 seconds.

You probably really need to figured out a divider for your messages: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/ip/tcp-connection-factories.html#tcp-codecs

im leaning against writing some form of custom deserializer, and then try to determine the end of the messages, since none of the ones provided by spring-integration sadly does not fit my needs

Well, that's possible, but hard to imaging what is that custom protocol for packages could be not fitting to any well-established practice of communications over the network.

its self defined protocol for a 3rd party service from the millenia, if i could burn it to the ground, i would.

Sure! Then custom (De)Serializer should help you to come up with the solution, if you are able to identify that protocol.
